# How to enable Bits Uploads on an IIS virtual directory using C# on Windows Server

Tags: c#, iis

I'm struggling to find a piece of C# to enable Bits Uploads on a virtual directory in IIS on any version of Windows Server.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=BITS&ac=4

Comment: sorry @JamieMeyer but this doesn't include the solution I'm looking for. I want to enable Bits on a virtual directory as you would manually in IIS but I want to do it via C# code.